# Procedurally bend curve from root

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, soft-body

I am trying to apply a softbody to a curve. Is it possible to not affect the 'root' origin?

I want the top of the curve to hang. As seen in the image, the left one is what I want the soft body to do. In this case I just used proportional editing, but I am searching for a procedural method to produce great variety while still being able to control and adjust it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

you can edit in properties(in edit mode)
weight 1 (stay) 0.01 (move)
strength(goal) set to 1

Comment: Oh completely missed the weight, this solved it, thanks a lot!